# TryParse not working when trying to parse a decimal number to an Int

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, int

I am trying to parse strings that may have a decimal. I'm using `Int32.TryParse` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my function where I try to parse:

```
private NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.Number;
private CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
public int? ParseInt(string node)
{
    int number;
    if (Int32.TryParse(node, styles, culture.NumberFormat, out number))
    {
        return number;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

And here is my unit test that is failing

```
[Fact]
public void TestParseIntWithDecimal()
{
    string provided = "28.789";
    int expected = 28;

    int? actual = _parser.ParseInt(provided);

    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

When I run my unit test, `null` is returned from `ParseInt` and I don't understand why. I thought `TryParse` could parse decimal numbers into integer numbers.

Comment: You could also just round the number first, so it's a whole number...

Comment: boy, this is how questions should be.  Simple, with working code that can be tested.  Nice.

Comment: In my now-removed answer I confused `AllowThousands` with `AllowDecimalPoint`, where the former can let `int.Parse()` parse numbers with commas (depending on culture). In some cultures comma is the decimal separator. It _does_ work if the fractional digits only contain zeroes (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(v=vs.110).aspx)): http://ideone.com/stQ9GY.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Parse`/`TryParse` methods are very strict. They don't accept any other types than the one you use as target. `28.789` is clearly not an `int` so it fails. If you want to truncate the decimal part you still have to parse it to `decimal` first. Then you can use `(int)Math.Floor(num)`.

```
private NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.Number;
private CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
public int? ParseInt(string node)
{
    decimal number;
    if (decimal.TryParse(node, styles, culture.NumberFormat, out number))
    {
        return (int) Math.Floor(number); // truncate decimal part as desired
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I did not realize how strict TryParse was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to refine the statement _"28.789 is clearly not an int so it fails"_ somewhat, `int.(Try)Parse` can handle decimals [as long as the fractional digits are all zeroes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(v=vs.110).aspx0).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Good point. But i haven't said that it fails if the input string contains decimal places.